# Rails, sitemap_generator, s3, how to write publicly available file to s3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, sitemap-generator-gem

I'm using sitemap_generator to create sitemap. 
I have a rake task to create s sitemap and to upload it to s3.

sitemap.rb

```
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.default_host = "https://www.ezpoisk.com"
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.create_index = true
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.public_path = 'tmp/'
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.sitemaps_path = 'sitemaps/'

SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.create do 
 # generating links ...
```

rake task

```
require "aws"

namespace :sitemap do
  desc "Upload the sitemap files to S3"
  task upload_to_s3: :environment do
    puts "Starting sitemap upload to S3..."

    s3 = AWS::S3.new(access_key_id: ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"],
                     secret_access_key: ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"])

    bucket = s3.buckets[ENV["S3_BUCKET_NAME"]]

    Dir.entries(File.join(Rails.root, "tmp", "sitemaps")).each do |file_name|
      next if ['.', '..', '.DS_Store'].include? file_name
      path = "sitemaps/#{file_name}"
      file = File.join(Rails.root, "tmp", "sitemaps", file_name)

      begin
        object = bucket.objects[path]
        object.write(file: file)
      rescue Exception => e
        raise e
      end
      puts "Saved #{file_name} to S3"
    end
  end

  desc 'Create the sitemap, then upload it to S3 and ping the search engines'
  task create_upload_and_ping: :environment do
    Rake::Task["sitemap:create"].invoke

    Rake::Task["sitemap:upload_to_s3"].invoke

    url = "https://www.ezpoisk.com/sitemaps/sitemap.xml.gz"
    SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.ping_search_engines(url)
  end
end
```

and I want to be able to serve if from s3 via my site so in routes

```
get "sitemaps/sitemap(:id).:format.:compression" => "sitemap#show"
```

and sitemaps_controller

```
  def show
    data = open("https://s3.amazonaws.com/#{ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME']}/sitemaps/sitemap#{params[:id]}.xml.gz")
    send_data data.read, :type => data.content_type
  end
```

Now. The problem.

when I run rake task and try to access file via the link I get 403 forbidden. I then go to s3 console and manually do "Make it public" on "sitemaps" folder. Now when I try to access file it's properly downloaded...
the problem is  - that when I run the task again ( I have a sidekiq job that does it once a day) I get 403 again... My assumptions is my write operation changes permissions on this.

the bucket itself has "allow list to everyone" permission.

I tried

```
 bucket = s3.buckets[ENV["S3_BUCKET_NAME"]]
 bucket.acl = :public_read
```

in the rake task, but it doesn't seem to take affect. 
I'm missing something, there has to be either way to set a flag on write to make it public, or maybe, I don't initialize it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. it's pretty simple/obvious (as usually) 
in rake task it should be

object.write(file: file, acl: :public_read)

coutesy of https://www.codefellows.org/blog/tutorial-how-to-upload-files-using-the-aws-sdk-gem